# How to copy an element in a RecyclerView

Tags: java, android

i'm trying to copy an element from the table of my RecyclerView when I click in the element.

This is my MainActivity.java:

```js
package com.example.caju1013.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.example.caju1013.myapplication.DataSource;
import com.example.caju1013.myapplication.R;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    MyAdapter myAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.drawerList);
        myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, getData1());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        //recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,2));
        // recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(3,1));
    }


    public static List<DataSource> getData1() {
        List<DataSource> data = new ArrayList<> ();

        int[] icons = {R.drawable.icon0, R.drawable.icon1,R.drawable.icon2,R.drawable.icon3,R.drawable.icon4,R.drawable.icon5,R.drawable.icon6,R.drawable.icon7,R.drawable.icon8,R.drawable.icon9,R.drawable.icon10};     //icon0 es el nombre de la imagen, todas estas imagenes tienen que estar guardadas en la carpeta drawable
        String[] titles = {"Circus", "Bridge", "Bar", "Building", "Fast food restaurant", "Business", "Car", "Hot dog", "Theatre", "Shopping resort", "Building"};
        String[] titles1={"648.847,765", "748.847,765", "848.847,765", "948.847,765", "848.847,765", "748.847,765", "648.847,765", "548.847,765", "448.847,765", "348.847,765"};
        String[] titles2={"4.823.976,876", "4.923.976,876", "4.823.976,876", "4.723.976,876", "4.623.976,876", "4.523.976,876", "4.423.976,876", "4.323.976,876", "4.223.976,876", "4.123.976,876"};

        for (int i = 0; i < icons.length && i < titles.length && i < titles1.length && i < titles2.length; i++) {
            DataSource tmp = new DataSource();
            tmp.pictureId = icons[i];
            tmp.pointName = titles[i];
            tmp.CoordX = titles1[i];
            tmp.CoordY = titles2[i];

            data.add(tmp);
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```

And this my Adapter.java:

```js
package com.example.caju1013.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context context;
    List<DataSource> data = Collections.emptyList();

    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<DataSource> data) {
        this.context = context;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, viewGroup, false);
        MyViewHolder viewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        //The position of the item within the adapter's data set.
        DataSource info = data.get(position);
        viewHolder.text.setText(info.pointName);
        viewHolder.CoordeX.setText(info.CoordX); //Enlazamos el mainactivity.java con el myadapter
        viewHolder.CoordeY.setText(info.CoordY);
        viewHolder.icon.setImageResource(info.pictureId);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }


    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

        TextView text;
        TextView CoordeX; //añadimos a la clase
        TextView CoordeY;
        ImageView icon;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.listText);
            CoordeX = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.listText2); // Asociamos el textview con el .xml
            CoordeY = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.listText3);
            icon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.listIcon);
            //Log.i("MyAdapter", "MyViewHolder()" + " " + String.valueOf(getPosition()));

            text.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            TextView tmp= (TextView)v;




            Toast.makeText(context, tmp.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    }

}
```

I think that I have to know the position of the element, but i don't know how to resolve it... Thanks!

Comment: which element you want to copy ?

Comment: I want implement the functionality that once is clicked on a TextView element of an item, the item is copied and appended to the dataset.

Comment: just clear my understanding that when you click on the textview value of that textview should get appended as the row in the recycleview ?

Comment: Yes, this is my objective =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
   viewHolder.text.setTag(info)
   viewHolder.text.setClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {  
           DataSource info = (DataSource)v.getTag(); 
           data.add(info);
           notifyDataSetChanged(); 

         }
       });
```